# Declaring and populating Attributes on a table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am doing a game database for a college assignment.

When creating the tables and declaring attributes I straight away populate them with values "INSERT INTO ..."

I am having difficulty on:

- Having an attribute called *"rental_limit"* which is a random value from 2 to 7 (representing the amount of days a game can be rented for) specifically declared in the *"game"* table, and having *"rental_date"* as attribute declared on a *"txn"* table, how can I declare a *"retur_date"* attribute which is the combination of those other two?

I assume it is possible but I am very new in databases / SQL and so far did not find an answer online anywhere and neither in my college books.

Note two tables example below:

```
CREATE TABLE game
(
    game_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    publisher VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    genre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    **rental_limit** TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
    rental_rate DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 4.50
);

INSERT INTO game (title, publisher, genre, rental_limit, rental_rate)  
VALUES ("A Game of Thrones: Genesis", "Focus Home Interactive", "Strategy", 5, "5.50"), 
       ("Ace of Spades", "Sierra Entertainment", "FPS", 3, "24.50"),
       (...etc)

CREATE TABLE Txn
(
    txn_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rental_date DATE NOT NULL,
    **return_date** DATE NOT NULL,
    game_id SMALLINT,
    staff_ID SMALLINT,
    cst_ID SMALLINT,

    FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES game(game_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(staff_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (cst_ID) REFERENCES Customer(cst_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Customer (rental_date) 
VALUES ("11/24/18"), ("03/20/12"), (etc...)
```

I my question makes sense, also my FK declaration is fine? will get populated from other tables with using REFERENCES?

Cheers :)

Comment: sounds more like something you need to do in `PHP` or `.NET`.  Why are you trying to do calculations in SQL pure?

Comment: @shadow how is this question in any way a duplicate of the linked question? Sure the guy has asked about some date math, but it's a tiny fraction of the question and the linked question is in no way an adequate answer for even 50% of what he's struggling with

Comment: @CaiusJardc the OP asked about how to calculate a date from another date and number of dates. The duplicate question provides the answer for that.

Comment: @apcs Welcome to SO. Sorry that your first question was closed - it's a reasonably common occurrence among first-questions from people, though I don't think it was apt in this case. As such I'll have to offer assistance via a few comments instead of posting an answer.. I'll put what you wrote in `code font`. You said `declaring attributes` - we tend to call them columns. `random value from 2 to 7` - insertion of values and hence calcualting random numbers is generally done by the front end code that forms the customer interface of your app. If you're set on doing this in mysql then use the..

Comment: `RAND()` function when you're inserting. RAND returns a float between 0 and 1, so to get it between 2 and 7 you'll need to do something like `FLOOR(2 + RAND() * 5)`. `how can I declare a "retur_date" attribute`- you probably don't want to do this. It makes sense that your game has a max days it can be rented for - popular games would be less in a real world situation. It also makes sense that your txn table has the dates from and to, but it DOESN'T really make sense that you calculate the return date from the rental start date + the max, and instantly store it into the table. In a real world..

Comment: situation you would write the current date into the txn table when the customer starts renting the game, and leave the return date null while they didnt already return it. This way you can query which games are out with `SELECT * FROM txn WHERE return_date IS NULL`, and you can run a report of which games are overdue with something like `SELECT * FROM game INNER JOIN txn ON game.id = txn.gameID WHERE DATEADD(rental_start-date, INTERVAL rental_limit DAY) < NOW()` and can then chase up the outstanding games. When the customer returns the game you can write a return date in, and then charge ..

Comment: an overage based on how man days over the `DATEADD(rental_start_date, INTERVAL rental_limit DAY)` the game is. You wrote: `INSERT INTO Customer (rental_date)` - hang on, i thought the table was called txn? `also my FK declaration is fine?` yes, theyre fine syntactically - that's how you'd create the, As to whether you've created the right keys, well that's more a question for you than us, but what you've put here loks sensible in the context of a real world rental shop. `will get populated from other tables with using REFERENCES?` - no, that's not what foreign keys are for...

Comment: An FK on the txn table referencing the game table will ensure that any txn you insert has a game id that exists in the game table (so people can't rent games that dont exist). You have to provide the game id to the INSERT INTO txn query, and mysql will check that the provided game id exists. There are additional rules like `CASCADE DELETE` which mean that if you delete a game, all transactions that reference the game will also be deleted, but that's not what I think you're asking about with the "populated automatically" comment

Comment: @Shadow - hopefully from the comments above you can see that he was asking a much larger and more involved question than "how do I add 2 days to a date in mysql", hence my complaint that your linked question goes nowhere near far enough to answering the questions he had. I realise that the more rep a person has, the easier it seems for them to forget the "be nice to newbies" mantra we have, but it's a core value of SO; please remember it when casting your heavy voting hand, because you can close questions without needing anyone else's opinion. I think you voted this one wrong

Comment: @CaiusJardchai the fact you chose to comment on the entire data structure, does not mean that the OP asked about how to restructure the data.

Comment: @CaiusJardchai Thank you very very much for your comments, it helped me immensely. I had searched for answers on my question and did not find them so useful as I am new to SQL and databases (my subject in college is introduction to DB) and I needed a constructed answer to understand why and how I do what is required to reach the results.
Your explanation was more valuable than my lecture's class on it, so I really appreciate it. :)